# How to pass const char* from python to c function

Tags: python, ctypes, python-c-api

I am using `ctypes` in Python to open a file for writing in C++.

My C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
void openfile(const char *filename) {
    cout<<"File to open for writing = " <<filename<<endl;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(fp,"writing into file");
    fclose(fp);
}
}
```

My Python code:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/in/vrtime/mahesh/blue/rnd/software/test/test.so')
>>> outfile = "myfirstfile.txt"
>>> lib.openfile(outfile)
File to open for writing = m
```

I am getting the file name as `m`, which is the first `char` charater of my file.

How to pass whole string to the C side?

Comment: You need to convert from python strings to C++, pass something like `ctypes.c_char_p("myfirstfile.txt")`

Comment: I checked that but still not able to pass whole string to c side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In python3 (and you are definitely using python3 as on python2 your code would luckily work)
 strings are stored as `wchar_t[]` buffers, so when you pass `"myfirstfile.txt"`
the C function sees its arg as `"m\0y\0..."` which is obviously a C string of lenght one.
Here is the problem manifested:

```
In [19]: from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p

In [20]: libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

In [21]: puts = libc.puts

In [22]: puts('abc')
a
```

You should pass to the C function a `bytes` object

```
In [23]: puts(b'abc')
abc
```

You can convert `str` to `bytes` like this:

```
puts(my_var.encode())
```

To avoid further confusion you may specify the argument types of C function:

```
In [27]: puts.argtypes = [c_char_p]
```

Now the function accepts `bytes` (ctypes converts it to `char*`):

```
In [28]: puts(b'abc')
abc
```

but not `str`:

```
In [30]: puts('abc')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-aaa5b59630e2> in <module>()
----> 1 puts('abc')

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: Thanks. I did similar thing by using bytes("myfirstfile.txt", encoding="ascii") and it worked.